# Array initialization optimization

Tags: c++, x86-64, compiler-optimization, calling-convention, abi

When compiling the following code snippet (clang x86-64 `-O3`)

```
std::array<int, 5> test()
{
    std::array<int, 5> values {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}};
    return values;
}
```

[It produced](https://godbolt.org/z/iKXTAK) the typical assembly that I would expect

```
test():                               # @test()
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rip + .L__const.test().values+16]
        mov     dword ptr [rdi + 16], ecx
        movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rip + .L__const.test().values]
        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi], xmm0
        ret
.L__const.test().values:
        .long   0                       # 0x0
        .long   1                       # 0x1
        .long   2                       # 0x2
        .long   3                       # 0x3
        .long   4                       # 0x4
```

However for small arrays, it seems to have figured out a trick?

```
std::array<int, 3> test()
{
    std::array<int, 3> values {{0, 1, 2}};
    return values;
}
```

[This](https://godbolt.org/z/080Sp4) was the corresponding assembly

```
test():                               # @test()
        movabs  rax, 4294967296
        mov     edx, 2
        ret
```

Where did that magic number (`4294967296`) come from? Is that essentially a value that can be `reinterpret_cast` back into an array of `int` somehow?

Comment: On Godbolt you can mouseover a number to see it in Hex.  If you look at asm often, you're going to get used to `4294967...` being about 2^32 and thus a huge clue that you should look at the hex to see the upper/lower 32 bits.  (Or for numbers just *below* 2^32, that it's actually a negative 32-bit integer.)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A `std::array<int, 3>` is 96 bits wide on your implementation.  As such the ABI declares that it should be returned in RAX + the low 32 bits of RDX (aka EDX).

4294967296 is 2<sup>32</sup>, in hex it is `$1'0000'0000`.  So the `movabs` stores 0 in the low order 32 bits of RAX, and 1 in the high order bits of RAX.  The `mov` stores 2 in EDX (which is exactly what you wanted).

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks sasha for proposing the edit, and caf for doing it.

Comment: Fun fact: with BMI2 a probably more optimal way to compile this would be `mov edx, 2` and then [`rorx rax, rdx, 33`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RORX.html)  to create `1<<32` from the `1<<1`.  `movabs` is so big (10 bytes) that it's slow to decode and can take extra space in the uop cache.  `rorx` is 6 bytes (3-byte VEX + opcode + modrm + imm8) but its immediate is small.  It does have a dependency on the `mov`-immediate and can only run on the shift ports on Intel CPUs, but normally that's not a bottleneck (especially in a code path that leads to a `ret`, not contained in a tight loop)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think the optimizer can be forgiven for not spotting this particular possibility - it's *very* specific to the particular data pattern!

Comment: clang does look for things like `lea r64, [reg + disp8]` to create a 2nd large constant instead of 2x `movabs`.  e.g. see [Signed saturated add of 64-bit ints?](//stackoverflow.com/a/56531252) where clang uses `movabs  rcx, 9223372036854775807` ; `lea  rax, [rcx + 1]` to materialize `INT64_MAX` and `INT64_MIN` in RCX and RAX respectively, in versions of the function that need both.  https://godbolt.org/z/iD6Ml8  GCC just uses 2x `movabs` even with `-Os`

Comment: GCC and clang both look for optimizations like that in some cases: https://godbolt.org/z/wctons like using a `sub  rax, 120` to create a 2nd nearby constant instead of using another `movabs`.  They're not very good at it, though, and yeah probably aren't looking for the possibility of rotating :P